# Дайте пожалуйста совет по решению задачи (очереди в Python)

Tags: python, алгоритм, очередь

Строки в python сравниваются, учитывая коды символов `(“Я” > “Q”, “B” > “A”)`.
Создайте структуру данных для работы с очередями, где объекты имеют
приоритет.
Вам на вход будет подано несколько очередей, при разборе которых нужно
придерживаться правил: первой обрабатывается очередь, в которой находится
наибольшее кол-во объектов, при равных длинах очередей приоритет отдается
согласно приоритету крайнего объекта `(А > B > C)`.
Очередь задаётся строковой последовательностью символов, например:
ABBBCAABB.
Нужно реализовать функционал:
● инициализация очереди
● добавление объекта в конец очереди
● удаление первого объекта очереди
● имплементируйте для очередей операторы сравнения очередей

> , <, ==. Они должны отрабатывать в соответствии с логикой
> описанной в условии разбора очередей (бОльшая очередь,
> которая имеет бОльшую длину, а также согласно приоритету
> первого объекта)

```
ABB > BBB
AA < BBB
AA == AB
```

● функция/метод для разбора двух параллельных очередей
согласно логике разбора (подсказка: используйте для этого
операторы сравнения >,<,==)
● Ограничения: не используйте сложные структуры данных python
(deque и т.д.). Напишите реализацию с использованием
стандартных типов (строки, списки)[image: Пример]

Моя попытка:

```
class myDeque():
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.que = queue

    def print_queue(self):
        return print(self.que)

    def add(self, object):
        self.que = self.que + object

    def remove(self):
        self.que = self.que[:0] + self.que[1:]
        return self.que

    def size(self):
        return len(self.que)

def parse_deques(first_que,second_que):
    if first_que.size() == second_que.size():
        pass 
    if first_que.size() > second_que.size():
        pass
    if first_que.size() < second_que.size():
        pass
    pass


a = myDeque('AABB')
a.remove()
a.add('B')
a.print_queue()
print(a.size())
```

Comment: Вы сами ничего пытаться даже не будете?

Comment: Я реализовал класс очереди, и начал писать функцию parse_deques, но абсолютно нет уверенности что я иду в правильном направлении

Comment: Дак вы пишите, даже если окажется тупиковый путь, вы чему-то научитесь. Overthinking это такая вещь, которая не лечится думанием. Она лечится деланием.

Comment: Вы сразу создаете готовую очередь - a = myDeque('AABB') , а надо в нее аппендить объекты. Не знаю, может каким-нибудь случайным образом, вкладывать и по таймеру доставать?

Comment: Вообще задание вызывает только раздражение, работать с очередями и не использовать deque? Неужели не хватает фантазии преподавателям задать примеры приближенные к жизни, просто посмотрев stackoverflow или другие форумы.